# time since factory reset android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to log time reliable how long a device is run. I've tried my best with `BOOT_COMPLETED` `BroadcastReceiver`. Due to the fact that all receiver are removed if an app is force stopped this method is not working for me.

I was wondering if there is a way to get the uptime of an Android device since the last factory reset has been performed?

The Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".TestReceiver" 
        android:enabled="true" 
        android:exported="true" 
        android:label="Test Receiver" >
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Receiver Code:

```
public class TestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.i("bootreceiver", intent.toString());
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, I know it's a lot of time since the question was asked. But were you able to get the time since factory reset on non- rooted device?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone reaching this actually looking for a answer to the title question:

You can try getting the install time for one of the system packages, for instance:

```
long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long installTime = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.android.providers.applications", 0).firstInstallTime;
long timeDiff = curTime - installTime;
```

Comment: Are you sure that the package name of "com.android.providers.applications" is available and accessible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not pretty sure how do you want to calculate uptime from factory reset, not from last reboot. However, if you are storing some of your data and checking was it erased on boottime - it might work.

However, I think here is a good idea to use BroadcastReceiver for BOOT_COMPLETED. And it's generally false that receivers are deleted after force close. It applies only for receivers from code.

Instead, you can define your receiver in Manifest - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html
If you'll do - it will be executed each reboot, regardless of anything.

Good luck

Comment: I define my receiver in Manifest, but I don't receive any Broadcasts after force closing my App. This happens for devices running API level 11 and above.

Comment: Sorry, when do you expect to get this Broadcast? I think after reboot, right? And when FC did happen? On previous device launch? Do you really think it matters?
One more thing - are you sure that you are really Rebooting the phone? Not using "Power-Off" - "Power-On". Because if you are - you will not get Broadcast on modern phones, which supports Fast Boot

Comment: The force close happens before I reboot the phone and I expect the Broadcast after reboot and I don't get the Broadcast even if I Reboot and not use "Power-Off" - "Power-On".
Is there a way to get Broadcast on Phones with FastBoot anyhow?

Comment: That's strange. Are you sure that you'd set RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission to your app?
Anyway, I would recomment to LogCat the device while it's loading and pay attention on all mesages, related to your app and BOOT_COMPLETED event. I'm pretty sure crash before reboot cannot impact on receiving a new broadcast after reboot.

Comment: Yes I'm sure that I set the permission, because I receive the BOOT_COMPLETED event on devices running API 9 and below. I wrote a test app to LogCat the events I receive.

Comment: That's weird. I'm pretty sure it's working on API 16.
So can you please edit the initial post with pasting there your Manifest?
Also, you can try to execute "adb reboot" to be sure fastboot is not active and broadcast will be sent.

Comment: I tried "adb reboot" and use API 16 and still no Broadcast at all :/

Comment: Please check my new answer. You'd really had a problem with permission in manifest. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem defining permission in your Manifest.
It should look like that:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".TestReceiver" 
        android:enabled="true" 
        android:exported="true" 
        android:label="Test Receiver" >
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

You should define you app's permission in Uses block. And the permssion that you'd added to your Broadcast - it does not add you a permission to receive it, it just forces any other app, that can trigger your broadcast, to have this permission. So unuseful in your case.

Hope it helps

Comment: Edited my Manifest but still no Broadcast -.- Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: Auch, sorry, I didn't notice that you'd defined a wrong intent filter also. You should use android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED instead of android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN. Please check it now

Comment: This is weird, still no Broadcast.

Comment: The last try: did you actually remove 'android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"' from your broadcast declaration, or you have the manifest now like in edited post? Just be sure you'd removed this attribute.

Comment: Yes the attribute is actually removed edited the manifest to look like my actual manifest. Sorry for the misleading edit and thanks a lot for trying to help me!

Comment: Ok, as for now Manifest looks good. Can you please paste a code of your entire Receiver?